# How to use weights from survey package in TermDocumentMatrix

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, survey

I work a lot with samples that I want to generalize to larger populations. However, most times the samples are biased and need to be weighted with the [survey](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/survey.pdf) package. However, I have not found a way to weight Term Document Matrix on these kind of weights. Consider this example

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)

set.seed(123)

# Consider this example: I have performed a sample from a population and now have 
# 1000 observations of text. In the data I also have information about gender.

# The sample
data <- rbind(data.frame(gender = "M",
                  words =  sample(c("education", "money", "family",
                                    "house", "debts"),
                                  600, replace = TRUE)),
              data.frame(gender = "F",
                    words =  sample(c("career", "bank", "friends", 
                                      "drinks", "relax"),
                                    400, replace = TRUE)))
# I create a simple wordcloud
text <- paste(data$words, collapse = " ")
matrix <- as.matrix(
  TermDocumentMatrix(
    VCorpus(
      VectorSource(text)
    )
  )
)
```

Which produces a wordcloud that looks something like this:
[image]

As you can see, the terms mentioned by men are bigger because the appear more often. However, I know the true distribution of this population, thus this wordcloud is biased.

The true gender distribution

```
true_gender_dist <- data.frame(gender = c("M", "F"), freq = nrow(data) * c(0.49,0.51))
```

With the survey package I can weight the data with the rake function

```
library(survey)
rake_data <- rake(design = svydesign(ids = ~1, data = data),
                  sample.margins = list(~gender),
                  population.margins = list(true_gender_dist))
```

In order to use the weights in analysis, visualizations etc. (that are not included in the survey package) I add the weights to the original data.

```
data_weighted <- cbind(data, data.frame(weights = weights(rake_data)))
```

So far so good. However, I would like to make a wordcloud that take these weighs into consideration.

My first attempt would be to use the weights in making the Term Document Matrix.

```
text_corp <- VCorpus(VectorSource(text))
w_tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(text_corp,
                                control = list(weighting = weights(rake_data)))
```

But then I get:

```
Error in .TermDocumentMatrix(m, weighting) : invalid weighting
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: You don't need `sample` for the 'gender' columns in your example. `data.frame(gender = 1, ...` will do

Comment: You could possibly use the [inverse document frequency (idf)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) to weight the term frequencies. Or just divide the term frequencies for each gender by the number of surveys from each gender.

Comment: Yeah, @emilliman5, it was something like that that I had in mind too. Just not sure how I would program it. Guess I'll have to try around with the TM-package which has a function for specifying weights. Since the weights also may regard things as political bias, age etc I'm looking for a more sophisticated way.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so I'll use the answer to comment your question:

You could be interested in the R package stm (structured topic models). It provides possibilities to infer latent topics regarding meta variables (continuous and/or discrete).

You can generate different kinds of plots to check out how metavariables influence

a) the selected topics depending,

b) the preferred words inside one topic,

c) and some more :)

Some links, if you're interested:

[Paper describing the R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stm/vignettes/stmVignette.pdf)

[R documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stm/stm.pdf)

[Some more Papers](http://www.structuraltopicmodel.com/) <-- this is a really good collection, if you want to dive into the subject some more!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Interesting package. However, if I remember correctly the TM-package also provide the ability to store meta variables, nevertheless, the stm-modelling is interesting. Still, not really the what I'm looking for. At its most basic form I am interested in giving each term frequency weights based on meta variables.